# HBase: Row key composition

Tags: hbase

For simplicity, lets say that I have a table where primary key should logically be a long.
At the moment, inherited from a project I did (that was using relational database) I have an IDMaker class that returns a long which I used (in that project) as primary key.

I say could because, as far as I understood, since this ID is timestamp based and monotonically incremented, it is not a good candidate for a HBase row key.

Now, reading the

http://ikaisays.com/2011/01/25/app-engine-datastore-tip-monotonically-increasing-values-are-bad/ 
http://hbase.apache.org/book/rowkey.design.html
and the 9th chapter of "HBase: the definitive guide" by Lars George,

I see that the "Salting" stratety could fit my needs. That basically adds a prefix to my keys therefore breaking the monotonic series.
Now the question: using a strategy like this, starting from this ids:

1
2
3
4

assuming that those key go to one region server, and transforming those ids like this (the prefix is of course an example)

0:1
7:2
9:3
a:4

How can I be sure that the four rows won't still go to the same region server? In other words, how can I be sure that my prefix is enough to avoid what is nicely described here http://ikaisays.com/2011/01/25/app-engine-datastore-tip-monotonically-increasing-values-are-bad/ ?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I be sure that the four rows won't still go to the same region
>   server? In other words, how can I be sure that my prefix is enough to
>   avoid what is nicely described here

Did you read upon section 2.5.2.7. Managed Splitting in [Important Configurations](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#important_configurations) already?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I just read the section but, although something is more clear, my question remains...did you read the BigTable article above? I'd like to understand where the A-L and M-Z boundaries come from

Comment: Yes, I know Ikai's post. Now, what do you mean with 'where the boundaries come from'? From *you* :)

Comment: Ah, and one more thing. I'm wondering if you actually read the post carefully as the most important hint Ikai gives you on the way is sadly at the very end: 'don’t prematurely optimize for this case, since chances are, you won’t run into it.' - having said this, are you 100% certain you have this case?

Comment: Well, I'll try to explain better. I have the chance to insert a well-known prefix to my row keys, which naturally are incremented monotoncally. So no, I'm not sure I am in that scenario but I believe I have all the preconditions to meet it :-) Now having the possibility to insert a prefix, I would like to be sure that my prefix will be enough to distribute my rows among the regions / splits. But i cannot be sure until I'm not aware about how rows are distributed. A lot of example use a single byte as prefix...is that enough or (for example) a three-bytes prefix has a greater Randomness?

Comment: 1. Ikai's point was that unless you actually *experience* the 'hot tablet' case (in BigTable terms), don't waste your time on it. Think about it. 2. I'm happy to help if I can but I'd appreciate it if you'd up-vote my answer rather than thanking me in a comment (even if you don't want to accept it as the correct answer) ... this is the way things supposed to work here ;)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I be sure that the four rows won't still go to the same region server?

You should pre-split your table based on your hashing pattern.

For example if you will use 0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-A-B-C-D-E-F for salting. You can create 16 splits for that hbase table. Each split should has 0 as start - 1 as end row, 1 as start - 2 as end row .. like so. You can do this from hbase shell or java code. I prefer java, because i can use a for loop to create many number of splits :)

As for premature optimization, too many splits can effect your performance.